# 5-5-2-2 children custody schedule...how to create and repeat throughout year?

Tags: calendar, schedule

I am trying to create a custom google calendar, but one that shows somewhat of a complex schedule and repeats throughout the year. Specifically, I'd like to create a 5-5-2-2 calendar that describes days on with two, separated parents (essentially, 5 days with dad, 5 with mom, 2 with dad, 2 with mom, then repeat). This is pretty standard stuff in child custody, and you can pay for software that generates this calendar, but there must be a simpler way to do it in Google Calendar rather than hand keystroking it in each month. I am not a developer so any responses that are on the "simple language" side would be super helpful! Thank you to the community!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Is this a programming question? Asking because Stack Overflow is a programming question and answer site. And because I can write a Java program for this in not that many minutes, but am unsure whether this was what you asked for.